# Можно ли прокидывать ApplicationContext в ViewModel?

Tags: android

Я знаю, что есть AndroidViewModel, которая в параметры себе принимает application, но для чего именно нужен applicationContext в вью модели? Есть ли конкретные примеры применения такого контекста именно во вью модели? На практике application контекст ни разу не нужен был.

Comment: Для получения доступа к ресурсам обычно используется. В первую очередь по причине того, что никакой другой контекст во ViewModel для этого использовать нельзя

Comment: Контекст приложения отличается от контекста активити незначительно, в основном это могут быть отличия в настройках стиля, если стиль конкретной активити отличается от стиля всего приложения. Нет особой разницы какой контекст использовать в большинстве случаев (не считая нюансов по утечкам памяти). ViewModel использует контекст приложения чтобы избежать утечек памяти из за удержания активити, если ее надо будет уничтожить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.
Для этого существует `AndroidViewModel`.
Работа с ним точно такая же, как и с обычным `ViewModel`.
Единственное различие - создание самого класса (конструктов и класс-родитель).
Вам просто надо указать Aplication в конструкторе.
Инициализация объекта `AndroidVM` ничем не отличается от обычной `VM`

```
class VM(private val apl: Application) : AndroidViewModel(apl){
////
}
```

p.s. зачем это нужно на практике? самый банальный пример...

Есть TextView которое  отображает какой-то текст.
есть значение по умолчанию, которое устанавливается в это TextView из string.xml.
ну и сама "переменная" этого значения.

чтобы не делать однотипных операций несколько раз, просто при создании viewModel указываете, что значение по умолчанию берется из string'ов. а чтобы получить доступ к String.xml - надо иметь Контекст во ВьюМодели. или Application

а TextView отображает значение из viewModel.
и ваша задача остается только менять значение в самой модели.